# How to query TFS for work items closed by a specific person

Tags: tfs

Does anyone have a TFS query that returns results for a specific user who has closed a work item?

I can not figure out a way to only bring back who closed the item.  Instead my query is keying off if the work item was ever changed by a specific user.  Thus the results are coming back for that user if they make a comment on the work item, but didn't actually close it, etc.

Comment: Can you share your query so far? And have you had a good look at the fields available to you? (e.g. ` System.ClosedBy`: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/track/query-by-workflow-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use TFS API to get work items history, then get Changed By field and State field in the same revision to achieve what you want.

Useful blog: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Closed By" field to query this list:
[image]